# Editor's undo does not track pastes

Tags: feature-request, editor

The editor doesn't seem to know when a paste occurs.

Example: Open a new editor (either to write a new post or to edit an existing one), and paste some text as the first thing you do. Notice that the undo button is not enabled and Ctrl+Z (since it is overridden by the editor) doesn't work either. You *can* right-click in the textarea and select "undo", since the editor doesn't override that.

As a sidenote, why is the editor even handling undo? All the browsers already do that anyway.

---

**Update**: I've tested on all the browsers I have here on my work PC (WinXP SP3).

- Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702: Non-reproducible
- Safari 4 Public Beta (528.17): Reproduced
- Opera 9.64: Reproduced
- Firefox 3.5.5: Reproduced
- Chrome 3.0.195.33: Reproduced

In addition, on Safari, Chrome, and Firefox, pasting twice in a row enables the edit button, while in Opera I can paste all day and it is never enabled. Also, if the pastes are not consecutive (i.e. if I paste, click elsewhere, and paste again) the undo button is not enabled in Safari/Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: I can replicate this in Firefox.

Comment: Oddly enough, pasting something twice will trigger the Undo button. I can replicate this in FireFox and Chrome, but not IE8

Comment: Can replicate the same in Chrome 4.0.266

Comment: Concur. Can't replicate in IE 8.0.6001.18702.

Comment: Concur. Mozilla Firefox requires double paste..

Comment: See also [__Ctrl+Z undoes twice in editor__](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167885/ctrlz-undoes-twice-in-editor?rq=1)

Comment: FYI [An option to disable the editor's undo/redo feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289087/178179)