# Ctrl+Z undoes twice in editor

Tags: bug, editor, undo

When I press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the editor for Ask/Answer question, my last 2 modifications are undone.

What I mean is, that if I press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the text will not be the same as before I pressed <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. I need to press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> twice, not once, for that.

As an example, if I select and delete all the text, then write some new text, then hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the new text disappears AND the old text reappears.

This might not be obvious at first because changing the cursor position is considered a separate action, so it might look like <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't undo 2 actions, but in reality, it also changes the cursor.

I'm on Google Chrome, but I just tested on Firefox and this happens there too.

Comment: I'm seeing this behavior too, but is there anything they can do about it? Text boxes are mostly rendered and controlled by the operating system. Not saying they definitely can't change this behavior, but not sure they can. Also not sure if it's desirable -- it appears to be standard behavior. If I open a text pad in a different program (not a web browser), I'm also seeing that behavior.

Comment: I tried it in the Reply box for some forums, and there Ctrl+Z works normally. So it's not a problem of the browser itself.

Comment: @BenLee This undo is not controlled by the browser / OS.

Comment: I've stumbled across this bug a few times too, it's really annoying. There's some JS interfering with the browser's undo. It's especially annouying if you paste some text and immediately hit Ctrl+Z, a large portion of the text you typed before the paste will also be removed, even if you wait a few seconds between typing and pasting.

Comment: I see this as well and found this report when I came here to report the same thing. It's very irritating. Firefox 22.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. I think it would be better to just leave undo up to the browser if possible.

Comment: FYI [An option to disable the editor's undo/redo feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289087/178179)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross-site duplicating the answer of Stack Overflow Meta [Double revert when pressing `Ctrl`+`Z` after pasting in an answer field. Pasting something is a forgotten step so that two steps get reverted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416215/double-revert-when-pressing-ctrlz-after-pasting-in-an-answer-field-pasting?noredirect=1#comment970071_416215):

*Making [another one's comment on that linked Q/A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3799241/chivracq) an answer, here is at least a good workaround:*

If you run into a double reverting `Ctrl+Z`, just press `Ctrl+Y` once and it will be as if `Ctrl+Z` was done just once.

And whoever reads this and can fix this editor bug of over a decade, please do so.

Answer (score 8):

**Great question**, I had ran into this a few times too.

Basically the editor does not recognize **cut** as an undoable operation.

So if I CUT something, then press CTRL+Z, it undoes my CUT **and** one previous operation.

Comment: Minor correction - this happens for Delete as well as Cut (i.e. pressing Del as opposed to Ctrl+X).

Comment: And paste, as well.