# CUT & Paste are not considered undoable operations

Tags: bug, editor

I finally figured out why the text editor sometimes behaves unexpectedly.
Basically it doesn't consider *cut* or *paste* as undoable operations.  So, if I *cut* something, there is no entry in the undo stack, and if I paste, it doesn't count as undoable either.

This is a problem in weird cases, like say you do the following operations:

1. Format text via CTRL+K
2. Cut out several lines of text via CTRL+X
3. Paste in some foreign text.
4. Hit UNDO to remove that foreign text.
5. Suddenly you are back at step 1), where you *just formatted the text*.

Many other scenarios are possible. Kinda frustrating.

Related:

- [Editor's undo does not track pastes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32924/editors-undo-does-not-track-pastes?rq=1)
- [Ctrl+Z undoes twice in editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167885/ctrlz-undoes-twice-in-editor?rq=1)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Shog9: I get the same history issues with cut and paste on Firefox.

Comment: Ok - reproduced so far in Chrome, Firefox and IE 11..

Comment: I'm on a Chrome/Mac OS right now.  Also happens in Safari/Mac OS.

Comment: Not unrelated: [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2980).  Disabling hotkeys means losing CTRL+K for formatting (but retaining it for killing), and at least on OSX undo/redo is handled better natively.