# Undo feature in SE Web Markdown editor is exhibiting unexpected behavior in Safari and Firefox on OS X

Tags: bug, editor

Using undo in the editor is not undoing the previously entered text only, it's also undoing the last pasted content, e.g., I paste some text, type a word, hit CMD-Z to undo, and the word I typed **plus** the text I pasted in just before it is also undone. Sounds minor, but it's bitten me several times. This is happening in Safari 8 and 8.1 and Firefox 34.0.5 in both OS X 10.10 and 10.11.

Comment: This effect may be related to the cause of a similar bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32924/editors-undo-does-not-track-pastes?rq=1

Comment: As well as this report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167885/ctrlz-undoes-twice-in-editor?rq=1

Comment: They were reported 5 years and 1 year ago, respectively....