# An option to disable the editor's undo/redo feature

Tags: feature-request, editor

It would be great to have an option to disable the editor's undo/redo feature.

Motivation: it causes some annoying issues, e.g.:

- [Ctrl+Z undoes twice in editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167885/178179)
- [Editor's undo does not track pastes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32924/178179)

and some users may prefer their browser's default undo/redo.